# How to use jest in react native for unit testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

Here I am trying to implemnet jest unit testing . There are 2 files test and mock . In below code I am excuting test file (npm run test Contactdetails-test). But getting error
     FAIL  **tests**/Contactdetails-test.js
  × find Contact details info (5ms)
   ● find Contact details info

```
ReferenceError: MockedProvider is not defined


 Contactdetails-mock.js
        import react from 'react-native';
        import Contactdetails from '../app/components/container/ContactdetailsContainer';
        import { __generator } from 'tslib';

        const contactDetails = `[{"contactDetails":{"isContactBySms":"Y","mobileNo":"8880995809","isContactByPost":"N","isContactByEmail":"Y","emailId":"test@test.com"},"socialMediaDetails":{"socialMediaDetail":[{"name":"twitter","link":"HARIRAM@twitter.com","__typename":"SocialMediaDetail"},{"name":"facebook","link":"VarnaHERO@facebook.com","__typename":"SocialMediaDetail"},{"name":"linkedIn","link":"linkedIn@linkedin.com","__typename":"SocialMediaDetail"},{"name":"instagram","link":"instagram@instagram.com","__typename":"SocialMediaDetail"},{"name":"telegram","link":"kaushik@telegram.com","__typename":"SocialMediaDetail"}]}}]`;
        const contactDetailsinfo = JSON.parse(contactDetails);
        console.log("contact info", contactDetailsinfo);


        export const ContactDetailsData = {
            customerInfo: { contactDetailsinfo },

        }

    // Contactdetails-test.js

    import React from 'react';
    import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
    import ContactDetailsData from '../__mocks__/Contactdetails-mock';
        expect(findElement(tree,'Contactdetails.customerInfo','Contactdetails.navigation','')).toBeDefined();

    //   });

    it('find Contact details info', () => {

        renderer.create(
            <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
                <ContactDetailsData />
            </MockedProvider>,
        );
    });
```

Please help